# Laravel - How to save an Array to Database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array like this :

```
array:4 [▼
  "*name1*" => 1
  "*name2*" => 1
  "*name3*" => 2
  "*name4*" => 1
]
```

And I have an table **Item** with `'id'; 'name'; 'time'`

Then how to I can save this array into Item Table using Laravel ?

I already do this but I know it's not working. But I don't know how to save it

```
foreach ($data_participant[$i]['attributes']['stats']['itemGrants'] as $key => $value) {
      $itemGrants = new ItemGrant;
      $itemGrants->item = $key;
      $itemGrants->time = $value;

      $itemGrants->save();
}
```

Comment: What's the error ? or array  `$data_participant[$i]['attributes']['stats']['itemGrants']` might be empty ?

Comment: Is `ItemGrant` is an eloquent model?If yes, which table is represented by the model?

Comment: Hello @SagarGautam : No it's not empty. It's array as I was writing above. There is no error happens. But it not save to database.

Comment: Hello @MASh : Yes, it's an eloquent model. The table is "Item" as I was writing.

Comment: @NguyenHoang So, have you defined table name in model ? since your naming doesn't follows the model and table name convention

Comment: @SagarGautam yes I already define with protected table in Model :( I don't know why :(

Comment: Does your foreach loop is inside transaction and some error causing this problem ?

Comment: May I ask why  `$itemGrants = new ItemGrant;` inside the loop ?

Comment: Hello all guys, this is my mistake. I forgot check my grammar table name in protected $table. My bad. I'm sorry. Thank for your time.

Comment: @NguyenHoang Congrats you have find solution :D

Answer (score 6):

Just simply use `json_encode` function to convert from `array` to `JSON` string. You may refer to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for further information.

For example, convert your array to JSON string format:

```
$array = ["name"=>1,"name2"=>2,"name3"=>3];
$json_array = json_encode($array);
```

Now, the output will be a JSON string:

```
[{"name":"1"},{"name2":"2"},{"name":"3"}];
```

You can save it to a database as a string in JSON format.

If you want the data back in an array, then you have to decode. For example:

```
$string_json = "[{"name":"1"},{"name2":"2"},{"name":"3"}]";    
$array_output = json_decode($string_json,true);
```

Note the `true` boolean parameter passed to `json_decode`, this is important as without it `json_decode` will return an array of `stdObject` rather than an associative array.

Now, you can get back the array as your input.